# How to add a new sidekiq process?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

Currently, we have one process in Production serving all of our workers. How to add a new process/sidekiq instance?

Is there a way to spawn a new process that would be dedicated to a specific queue?

Answer (score 0):

For all things Sidekiq, [the Sidekiq Documentation](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/) is the best place to start.

In your case, you'll be specifically interested in the "[Advanced Options](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options)" documentation.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ways:

1. [sidekiqswarm](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Ent-Multi-Process) for paid sidekiq pro
2. one terminal run `bundle exec sidekiq`. open anther terminal run `bundle exec sidekiq` too. Then, you got 2 processes now
3. put sidekiq service inside docker image. run 3 sidekiq docker instances for the sidekiq image. You got 3 processes